# self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)#Vector2(1,0) ; Attribute-error : 'module' object has no attribute 'Vector2'

Tags: python, object, module, pygame, attributeerror

> ```py
> self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)#Vector2(1,0) 
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Vector2'
> ```

I am having error with this and I don't understand what's the problem,I tried many things to fix this but the error pops the same

Replacing `Vector2` with `Vector2D` also doesn't helps 
I was trying to rotate the sprites so any alternative will also do
I also tried using `math.Vector2D` but it doesn't recognizes it and an Import Error pops out

```py
import pygame
import random
##from pygame import Vector2
from os import path
import os
import sys
import math
..
..

self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
```

Comment: `Vec2d` is the class. https://www.pygame.org/wiki/2DVectorClass

Comment: It has to be `self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(1, 0)`. See [`
pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html)

Comment: try importing ```pygame.math```. It is required per https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2

Answer (score 1):

The class which you are searching for is implemented int the [`pygame.math`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html).
See [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2)

So it has to be:

```py
import pygame
```

```py
self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(1, 0)
```

respectively

```py
from pygame.math import Vector2
```

```
self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but even after trying what you've said, an error appears saying an 'Import Error: No module named 'math' "
though i've downloaded it via pip/pip3
So please help me out with this .. !